# Link to page where Shortcut type is set to Shortcut to page on another website and open the link in a new window doesn't open in new window

Tags: episerver, optimizely

I am looking into having a main navigation link to an external site (screenshot #1) however, when I select the “open the link in a new window” (screenshot #2) doesn’t work and still opens the link in the same tab. Am I missing something or is Epi not working the way it should?

screenshot#1
[image]

screenshot#2

[image]

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the code that renders the link. It's possible the `target` attribute is not set.

Comment: This is Epi's inbuilt screen .so dont have any specific code

Comment: @FarhinShaikh He's asking about how the link is rendered, i.e. if it's using `PropertyFor` or some other way of rendering the link's HTML.

Comment: @TedNyberg I am not sure i understand  how the link is rendered. This is an Episerver Page with its settings defined in Shortcut property as highlighted (3) in the snapshot above. I apologize if i am misinterpreting your question